# C# DateTimeOffset to DateTime Conversion

Tags: c#, .net

Can somebody please explain to me why the following code returns DateTimeKind.Unspecified. I was expecting DateTimeKind.Utc:

```
DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset  = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTimeKind dateTimeKind = dateTimeOffset.DateTime.Kind;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Implicit cast operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.op_implicit?view=netframework-4.8) from `DateTime` to `DateTimeOffset` behaves as `DateTimeOffset` constructor. You can have a look at [sources](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetimeoffset.cs,799efb65ff67135d) for details

```cs
// Constructs a DateTimeOffset from a DateTime. For Local and Unspecified kinds,
// extracts the local offset. For UTC, creates a UTC instance with a zero offset.
public DateTimeOffset(DateTime dateTime) {
    TimeSpan offset;
    if (dateTime.Kind != DateTimeKind.Utc) {
        // Local and Unspecified are both treated as Local
        offset = TimeZoneInfo.GetLocalUtcOffset(dateTime, TimeZoneInfoOptions.NoThrowOnInvalidTime);
    }
    else {
        offset = new TimeSpan(0);
    }
    m_offsetMinutes = ValidateOffset(offset);
    m_dateTime = ValidateDate(dateTime, offset);
}
```

And [`ValidateDate()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetimeoffset.cs,b1179274c9696e21) returns `Unspecified` kind

```cs
...
// make sure the Kind is set to Unspecified
//
return new DateTime(utcTicks, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
```

The important point here is also described in [remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTimeOffset__ctor_System_DateTime_) of `DateTimeOffset` constructor

> This constructor's behavior depends on the value of the DateTime.Kind
>   property of the `dateTime` parameter:
>
> If the value of `DateTime.Kind` is `DateTimeKind.Utc`, the `DateTime` property
>   of the new instance is set equal to dateTime, and the `Offset` property is set 
>   equal to Zero.
>
> If the value of `DateTime.Kind` is `DateTimeKind.Local` or
>   `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, the `DateTime` property of the new instance is
>   set equal to dateTime, and the `Offset` property is set equal to the
>   offset of the local system's current time zone.

You are checking the input datetime `Kind` and extract `Offset` value based on it. The `DateTime` property of resulting `DateTimeOffset` is `Unspecified`, because `Offset` property already represented a date offset. [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.datetime?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) property of `DateTimeOffset` is also saying that

> The value of the `DateTime.Kind` property of the returned `DateTime`
>   object is `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.

Comment: Thanks.I understand your explanation. I just dont understand why it was designed like this. My assumption was that the DateTimeKind specified on the DateTimeOffset would be the same as its DateTime vaue.

Comment: They extract original `DateTimeKind` into `Offset` value, `DateTime` property of `DateTimeOffset` can't represent any valid kind after that, and it's being explicitly set to `Unspecified`